# Python and OpenCV executable with py2exe error. Missing dll. How to fix it?

Tags: python, opencv, py2exe

I tried out **py2exe** and it worked fine when I tried to create an executable for a [simple program](https://bitbucket.org/gaborvecsei/miniprojects/src/920f69659ba7b07246a5e76f4f174d806436ff29/Mini%20Python%20Projects/Most%20Frequent%20Words/Most_Frequent_Words.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).

But when I tried to create an .exe from a program where I used `cv2` (OpenCV) it said:

`error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll'`

This is my `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import cv2
import numpy
setup(console=['blur_faces.py'])
```

I have no idea what to do and how to fix it.

Comment: A good start would be to search/find the missing dll